# How to access console.log data programmatically

Tags: javascript, global-variables, console.log

I would like to write a code that automaticly saves `console.log`-s as global variables so I can access them.

Can anyone help me with this?

Thank you for your time and advice.

Comment: This might help: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/lets-extend-console-log-8641bda035c3

Comment: Don't do this. Use a debugger instead.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/